# How can i build a list of Methods for iterative try in Python?

Tags: python, list, methods

I have a Data strukture with differet levels like this:
Data1--Methode1--Data2--Methode2--Data3
Data2=Data1.methode1

Each level of data need different method to approach. I am wondering if i can build a list of Methode to "dig in", for example [Method1,Method2,...]. And I will write one loop to "dig" the data by trying all the methods in the list.

I have this idea because we type string in screen when we call a method in python, for example I type print() to call print function. Can we make the string of a method replaceable, so i can change print() to list() or something else?

So can i build such a "Method list"? If I can, what data type sould I use?

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: @Tibebes.M what lane do is almost what i want. But In my case Data is called with for example: Data2=Data1.methode1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python methods can be treated like variables.

Below is an example of two different method functions that contain no input arguments.

```
def method1():
    # do something
    return 1

def method2():
    # do something else
    return 2


methods = [method1, method2]

for m in methods:
    print(m())
```

You need to be careful about arguments, it makes it easier if they all expect the same input. Below is another example where two methods are added to a list, they both expect a single integer as an argument.

```
def method1(arg):
    # do something
    return arg*1

def method2(arg):
    # do something else
    return arg*2


methods = [method1, method2]

for m in methods:
    print(m(5))
```

Furthermore, we can consider the case where a method is trying something that may not work. For this we can add a try / except block to the loop. This will continue the loop if the method we are trying throws an exception.

```
def method0(arg):
    return arg/(arg - 5)

def method1(arg):
    # do something
    return arg*1

def method2(arg):
    # do something else
    return arg*2

methods = [method0, method1, method2]

for m in methods:
    try:
        print(m(5))
    except:
        print(f'{m.__name__} did not work')
```

produces the output

```
method0 did not work
5
10
```

Lets say you have a class object with functions/methods inside. Those can be added to a list like this:

```
class DataType:
    val = 5
    def method0(self, arg):
        return arg/(arg - self.val)
    
    def method1(self, arg):
        # do something
        return arg*1
    
    def method2(self, arg):
        # do something else
        return arg*2

# instantiate the class object
obj = DataType()

# add methods to list from the object
methods = [obj.method0, obj.method1, obj.method2]

for m in methods:
    try:
        print(m(5))
    except:
        print(f'{m.__name__} did not work')
```

Producing the same output as above

```
method0 did not work
5
10
```

Comment: thx, but what if I want to use Data.changeable_methode? Is it also ok with attribute?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Data.changeable_methode, is this a method that exists in a class variable?

Comment: yeah, I think so. It's a methode from Datatype class.

Comment: I added a section that ha a class called DataType, please let me know if this works for you.  Your naming conventions may be slightly different but the same principles should apply.

Comment: Ur answer is awsome. But in my case I don't know what class it is. I only know the name of method, and can use it. But I can't see where it comes. All the Methode is wrappered in the Module. It is too difficult to understand what is going on there. Thx for ur answer! It inspires me a lot. I know what to do next. I will try to contact the developer of this module.

Comment: You don't necessarily need the name of the class although it is good to know. Typically you can find this out by printing `type(myobj)`. If you have the name of the variable and the name of the function that is all you really need to add it to a list.

Comment: Its seems like I have made mistake. What i am facing is not methode but attribute.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the attribute?

Comment: The problem is done. I write a code to automatically get attribute of a input. I save all attribute name in list, and call all of it with a methode _get_attribute_, just like ur code. Thx for ur informative help, lane.